# program not adding up the shares from all different offices in one TotalAmount variable

Tags: c++

I am learining OOP in c++ and this program is meant to collect the shares from different offices and store each office's share in a variable named sharePerOffice and add those shares of all offices in one single variable (totalShare)(see in class nationalOffices private members).. but it is not adding them in the totalAmount variable.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class nationalOffices
{
private:
    int sharePerOffice;
    int totalShare;
public:
    nationalOffices();
    nationalOffices(int x);
    void setsharePerOffice(int value);
    void setTotalShare();
    int getTotalShare();
};
nationalOffices::nationalOffices()
{
    sharePerOffice = 0;
}
nationalOffices::nationalOffices(int x)
{
    totalShare = x;
    sharePerOffice = 0;
}
void nationalOffices::setsharePerOffice(int value)
{
    sharePerOffice = value;
}
void nationalOffices::setTotalShare()
{
    totalShare = totalShare + sharePerOffice;
}
int nationalOffices::getTotalShare()
{
    return totalShare;
}
int main ()
{
    int shares = 0;
    nationalOffices offices[5] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout <<"enter share for office number "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin >> shares;
        offices[i].setsharePerOffice(shares);
        offices[i].setTotalShare();
        system("cls");
    }
    cout <<endl;
    cout <<offices[0].getTotalShare();
}
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry i meant to write totalShare in line 8.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables, and observe its logical execution flow, what observations did you make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `offices` is an array of five different and distinct and unique `nationalOffices` object. Each object have their *own* set of member variables.

The `totalShare` member will be unique for each object, and unrelated to the member variables of every other object.

Instead of keeping it as a member variable, add the total to a local variable inside the `main` function.

Another possible solution is to make `totalShare` a `static` member variable, in which case it becomes a *class* variable, shared by all objects of the class.